# Class selectors and its effects

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS/HTML and I am not native English so I am having some problems understanding the relations between classes. I go with an example:

```css
.classA .classB {
  color: red
}

.classC {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<div class="classA">
  <p class="classB classC">
    This text is red
  </p>
</div>
```

My question is: why it is not applying the style defined in .classC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `.classA .classB` is more specific. Then `.classC`.

If you would write:

```
.classA .classC {color:blue}
```

Then it would be applied.

For more details you can take a look at [MDN CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 2):

This is due to [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

In simple words: the first rule is more specific than the second one, because it describes a very specific hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Because your first CSS rule has a higher *specifity*. (google that...)

In this particular case, simply said: "two classes beat one class"...

Answer (score 0):

It's because the rule with nested classes: `.classA .classB {color: red}` has more priority than simple `.classC {color:blue}`.